# Flink SQL Client & Iceberg on MinIo: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found

Tags: amazon-s3, hadoop, hive, apache-flink, flink-sql

Running into some issues trying to get a local environment set up to stream data fro Flink into an Iceberg table over MinIO.

```bash
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
```

This is the Dockerfile I use for Flink jobmanager/taskmanager & sqlclient

```
FROM flink:1.16.2-scala_2.12-java11

ENV HADOOP_VERSION=3.3.2

RUN APACHE_HADOOP_URL=https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/ \
    && HADOOP_VERSION=3.3.2 \
    && wget ${APACHE_HADOOP_URL}/common/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && tar xzvf hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && HADOOP_HOME=`pwd`/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}

ENV HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/opt/flink/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}/etc/hadoop:/opt/flink/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/opt/flink/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}/share/hadoop/common/*:/opt/flink/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}/share/hadoop/hdfs:/opt/flink/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/opt/flink/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/opt/flink/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/opt/flink/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}/share/hadoop/yarn:/opt/flink/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/opt/flink/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}/share/hadoop/yarn/*

COPY lib/flink-sql-connector-hive-3.1.2_2.12-1.16.2.jar /opt/flink/lib/
COPY lib/flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.16.2.jar /opt/flink/lib/
COPY lib/iceberg-flink-runtime-1.16-1.3.0.jar /opt/flink/lib/
COPY lib/iceberg-hive-runtime-1.3.0.jar /opt/flink/lib/
COPY lib/hive-metastore-3.1.3.jar /opt/flink/lib/
COPY lib/hadoop-aws-3.3.2.jar /opt/flink/lib/
COPY lib/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.1026.jar /opt/flink/lib/

COPY lib/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.16.2.jar /opt/flink/plugins/

WORKDIR /opt/flink
```

And these are the docker-compose service definitions:

```yaml
  sqlclient:
    container_name: sqlclient
    build: flink
    command:
      - /opt/flink/bin/sql-client.sh
      - embedded
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    environment:
      - ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS=flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.16.2.jar
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=minio
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=minio123
      - AWS_REGION=us-east-1
    volumes:
      - ./flink-sql:/etc/sql

  jobmanager:
    build: flink
    hostname: "jobmanager"
    container_name: "jobmanager"
    expose:
      - "6123"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      - ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS=flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.16.2.jar
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=minio
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=minio123
      - AWS_REGION=us-east-1

  taskmanager:
    build: flink
    hostname: "taskmanager"
    container_name: "taskmanager"
    expose:
      - "6121"
      - "6122"
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    links:
      - jobmanager:jobmanager
    environment:
      - ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS=flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.16.2.jar
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=minio
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=minio123
      - AWS_REGION=us-east-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're copying the S3 plugin to the root of the `plugin` folder. To use a pluggable file system, you have to copy the corresponding JAR file to a directory under plugins directory of your Flink distribution before starting Flink.

More on this can be found at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/filesystems/plugins/